# MSSQL select based on most recent timestamp

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

I have done some research but have found examples that don't seem to be what I need. My table structure is something like this:

```
Hostname    Filename    Timestamp

Host1       ***.exe     2014-09-09 12:01:45.000
Host1       ***.pdf     2014-08-09 12:01:45.000
Host1       ***.ide     2014-07-09 12:09:44.000
Host1       ***.ide     2014-12-31 12:00:00.000
Host2       ***.exe     2014-09-09 12:01:45.000
Host2       ***.pdf     2014-08-09 12:01:45.000
Host2       ***.ide     2014-07-08 12:09:44.000
Host2       ***.ide     2014-12-29 12:00:00.000
```

With a few hundred hosts, and hundreds of thousands of files for each host. What I am trying to get is ONE .IDE file from each host - whichever has the latest timestamp. So in this case, I would like to return:

```
Host2       ***.ide     2014-12-29 12:00:00.000
Host1       ***.ide     2014-12-31 12:00:00.000
```

I have tried the following but it does not seem to be what I want, and I cant quite figure out why, I know it is wrong though:

```
select hostname, filename, max(timestamp) as timestamp from TABLE where
filename like '%.ide%'
group by hostname,filename
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you use group by

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```
select t.*
from table t
join (
    -- gets the maximum timestamp per hostname for "ide"
    SELECT max(Timestamp) as maxTime, hostname
    from table
    where filename like '%.ide%'
    group by hostname
) s on t.hostname = s.hostname
    and t.timestamp = s.maxTime
where t.filename like '%.ide%'
```

Basically it's selecting * from your main table, where the records can be successfully joined on the subquery which identifies the maximum timestamp per hostname for "ide"

Comment: Okay great, I'll try this. I actually kind of lied there are many more fields in the table that don't matter. So for the original line can I just do: select t.hostname, t.filename, t.timestamp instead of t.*?